# C++ Qt "unsupported version" error for glsl shader

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm trying to make Qt console app, which will launch compute shaders, but on launch it gives me following error:

```
QOpenGLShader::compile(Compute): 0(1) : error C0201: unsupported version 44
0(1) : error C0206: invalid token "<invalid atom 284073152>" in version line
```

Shader is tested and correct (it works fine in my openFrameworks based program) and starts with

```
#version 440
```

In Qt-based program I initialize OGL context in main.cpp with following code

```
QSurfaceFormat surfaceFormat;
surfaceFormat.setMajorVersion(4);
surfaceFormat.setMinorVersion(4);
surfaceFormat.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(surfaceFormat);

QOpenGLContext openGLContext;
openGLContext.create();
if(!openGLContext.isValid())
{
    qDebug()<<"Failed to create openGL context";
    return 0;
}
QOffscreenSurface surface;
surface.create();
if(!surface.isValid())
{
    qDebug()<<"Failed to create surface";
}
```

and then compile shader with

```
QOpenGLShaderProgram compute;
compute.addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Compute,":/shaders/cull.glsl");
compute.link();
```

Is there any Qt-specific things that I am missing?

Comment: Not really related, but how did you bind a buffer to your compute filter?  I know how to do it in QML with render passes, but I'm having trouble and can't find any examples on how to do this in C++.  I can't find any evidence of my compute shader even running, despite my `glDispatchCompute` call.

Comment: @Matt I've rewritten most of process using QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core class and openGL calls, but when it was more based on Qt wrappers, I was using QOpenGLBuffer's create(), bind() and allocate() and then still QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core->glBindBufferBase(). And shader was linked and binded before.

Comment: I've been using `QOpenGLExtraFunctions`, I'll try `QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core`  I'm also doing a `create()`, `bind()`, and `allocate()`, but there's no change in my data after `glDispatchCompute` (I `read()` back into the buffer to check.)  From your comment, it sounds like I'm on the right track.  If I can't get it, I'll write up a proper SO question; if so, mind if I post the link in a comment here to ask you again for help?

Comment: @Matt, you are welcome. I'm just learning glsl myself, so trying to find answer to your question may give me progress also)

Comment: Great!  Thanks for the help.  I've condensed my code and question into one hopefully well articulated [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42444493/compute-shader-not-writing-to-buffer).  I'm convinced my problem is something tiny that I'm missing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem was a bit unexpected for me. Shader file was saved by Visual Studio, so it has windows encoding. OpenFrameworks program was built also by Visual Studio, so it has no problem with launching shader, but Qt wasn't able to deal with windows-encoded EOLs. Resaving shader file in UTF-8 fixed problem.