# Compute Shader not writing to buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, compute-shader

I'm looking for help calling a compute shader from Qt using `QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core` OpenGL functions.

Specifically, my call to `glDispatchCompute(1024, 1, 1);` does not seem to have any effect on the buffer bound to it.  **How do you bind a buffer to a compute shader in QT such that the results of the shader can be read back to the C++**?

I create my program and bind it with ([Squircle.cpp](https://gist.github.com/kheaactua/8e1f78a07fa2ab2ac2e60b0a23444318#file-squircle-cpp)):

```
    computeProgram_ = new QOpenGLShaderProgram();
    computeProgram_->addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Compute, "../app/shaders/pointcloud.comp");
    computeProgram_->bindAttributeLocation("Particles", 0);
    m_ParticlesLoc = 0;

    computeProgram_->link();
```

And then bind my `QOpenGLBuffer` with ([Squircle.cpp](https://gist.github.com/kheaactua/8e1f78a07fa2ab2ac2e60b0a23444318#file-squircle-cpp)):

```
    // Setup our vertex buffer object.
    pointOpenGLBuffer_.create();
    pointOpenGLBuffer_.bind();
    pointOpenGLBuffer_.allocate(pointBuffer_.data(), pointBuffer_.vertexCount() * pointBuffer_.stride_);
```

Then I invoke the compute shader with ([Squircle.cpp](https://gist.github.com/kheaactua/8e1f78a07fa2ab2ac2e60b0a23444318#file-squircle-cpp)):

```
computeProgram_->bind();

// ... 

pointOpenGLBuffer_.bind();

glDispatchCompute(1024, 1, 1);
```

But when I read my buffer, either with `read()` or by `map()`'ing, the values are never changed, they're just what I originally inserted.

From the compute shader perspective, I accept my input with ([pointcloud.comp](https://gist.github.com/kheaactua/8e1f78a07fa2ab2ac2e60b0a23444318#file-pointcloud-comp)):

```
#version 430

layout(local_size_x = 1024) in;

struct ParticleData
{
    vec4 position;
};

// Particles from previous frame
layout (std430, binding = 0) coherent buffer Particles
{
    ParticleData particles[];
} data;
```

Am I not binding my buffer properly maybe?  Or is there another OpenGL command to call to actually dispatch the compute?  I've tried different usages, etc.

I've posted all the relevant code [here](https://gist.github.com/kheaactua/8e1f78a07fa2ab2ac2e60b0a23444318).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that problem is in wrong buffer binding understanding.

```
pointOpenGLBuffer_.bind();
```

only binds your buffer to your OGL context, not to your shader buffer, calling it twice won't do the trick.

Second time instead of just bind you need to call

```
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, pointOpenGLBuffer_.bufferId());
```

where 0 comes from your layout (std430, binding = 0)

Comment: It worked!  I had read that function last last night too, but didn't try it for some reason.  I also think my attention got caught on what `Format` I was using (I specify `Core4.3`, but the current buffer uses `Compatibility4.5`)  But yeah, thanks!  ~16 hours of my own toiling missed that solution. :)